# finding matching pairs in two sets in O(nlogn)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

There is a set A and set B of size n, for every card in set A there is a corresponding card in set B.

Describe a more efficient algorithm with an average case complexity of O(nlogn) tests to find the matching pairs. Prove that your algorithm satisfies the desired complexity.

I'm thinking I can just use quicksort to sort each set, that would be nlogn + nlogn, then i would know that the corresponding position in each set were matching pairs.  would this be correct?  Here is the problem in it's entirety

Each set consists of n cards and for every card in the set A there is a corresponding card in the set B that belong to the same account, and we will refer to these two cards as the matching pair. Each card is a small plastic object containing a magnetic strip with some encrypted number that corresponds to a unique account in the bank. It is required to find all matching pairs. There is a card reader machine such that when two cards, one from set A and one from set B, are inserted in the machine one of its three light indicators turns on; green if the pair matches, red if the account number on A is larger than B, and yellow if the number on B is higher than that of A. However, the card reader cannot compare two cards belonging to the same set.

Comment: What do you mean by matching? Are they equal? Then after sorting, set A shall be exactly equal to set B.

Comment: `However, the card reader cannot compare two cards belonging to the same set.` Implies you cannot quicksort.

Comment: You can't sort the sets because it says the card reader can't compare two cards belonging to the same set.

Comment: Also are the three light indicators supposed to represent `<` `==` and `>`?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal i'm not sure if it's that easy, it's possible he meant they have different values but they match to unlock an acount. doing an edit to the question posed.

Comment: @ShashankGupta you are right i didn't think about that. yes each light represents a < == >

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use card form A set as pivot for quick selection of set B. So you can implement quicksort in this way. So select one card from set A and divide B set to smaller and bigger. If you found matching card in B you can use this card to divide A set. If you not found matching card repeat. If found apply algorithm to smaller and bigger groups in same way as in quicksort. Repeat until you find all matching cards. Complexity is same as for quicksort, so O(n^2) in worst case and O(NlogN) in average.

Example implementation in Erlang:

```
-module(abcards).

-export([find_pairs/2]).

find_pairs([], _) -> [];
find_pairs(_, []) -> [];
find_pairs([A|As], Bs) ->
  case partitionB(A, Bs, [], [], not_found) of
    {_, _, not_found} -> find_pairs(As, Bs);
    {BLess, BMore, B} ->
      {ALess, AMore} = partitionA(B, As, [], []),
      [{A, B} | find_pairs(ALess, BLess) ++ find_pairs(AMore, BMore) ]
  end.

card_reader(A, B) when A > B -> red;
card_reader(A, B) when A == B -> green;
card_reader(A, B) when A < B -> yellow.

partitionB(_, [], BLess, BMore, Found) -> {BLess, BMore, Found};
partitionB(A, [B|Bs], BLess, BMore, Found) ->
  case card_reader(A, B) of
    red -> partitionB(A, Bs, [B|BLess], BMore, Found);
    green -> partitionB(A, Bs, BLess, BMore, B);
    yellow -> partitionB(A, Bs, BLess, [B|BMore], Found)
  end.

partitionA(_, [], ALess, AMore) -> {ALess, AMore};
partitionA(B, [A|As], ALess, AMore) ->
  case card_reader(A, B) of
    red -> partitionA(B, As, ALess, [A|AMore]);
    yellow -> partitionA(B, As, [A|ALess], AMore)
  end.
```

Comment: Care to share the analyzis, why is it same as quicksort? You have no idea if the 2nd card is bigger or smaller then the first (and so on), so have to compare against all cards again.

Comment: @amit: Yes, it is why there is O(n^2) in worst case.

Comment: @amit i only need the average case, should have mentioned that, i think this is right.  need to think about it some more, thanks for the help!

Comment: As far as I see it, your algorithm is: for each element in A: Partition B according to A until you find matching element. This will be `n/2+(n-1)/2 + (n-2)/2 + .... + 1/2`  ops on average, which is `O(n^2)` Am I missunderstanding your apporach?

Comment: PS I believe the solution do includes something similar, but a bit more complex and involves sorting both groups.

Comment: @amit: Yes, you misunderstanding mine approach. I have edited mine answer to be more explicit.

Comment: +1, but there's one minor inaccuracy: you will always find a matching card.  Regardless of which A-card Ai you choose as the initial pivot, you will compare it with *every* B-card, and we're told that every card matches some other card so you know you will find Ai's matching B-card, Bi.  After you then partition the A-cards using Bi, you have the two cards Ai and Bi plus 4 piles: A-small, A-big, B-small and B-big.  Recurse on (A-small, B-small) and on (A-big, B-big).

Comment: @j_random_hacker: You are right. I have missed it. It's nice this algorithm can work also with unmatched cards.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's wise to abuse Partition in this problem.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect):

> In quicksort, there is a subprocedure called partition that can, in linear time, group a list (ranging from indices left to right) into two parts, those less than a certain element, and those greater than or equal to the element.

Consider the following algorithm.

1. Pick any card from set A. Let's call it a<sub>1</sub>.
2. Partition set B around it using the card reader so that it will break up set B into 3 subsets, those equal to card a<sub>1</sub>, those less than card a<sub>1</sub>, and those greater than card a<sub>1</sub>.
3. There will always only be one card equal to card a<sub>1</sub>. Let's call this card b<sub>1</sub>.
4. Insert card b<sub>1</sub> into a "binary search tree" type thing along with its paired card a<sub>1</sub>
5. Pick another card from set A, call it a<sub>2</sub>.
6. Compare it with b1 using card reader, if it's less than b<sub>1</sub> run a partition on the subset from step (2) for which b<sub>k</sub> < a<sub>1</sub>. If it's greater than b<sub>1</sub> run a partition on the subset from step(2) for which b<sub>k</sub> > a<sub>2</sub>. This is O(n / 2) since we are running partition on a smaller set.
7. Take card from set B which is equal to a<sub>2</sub>, call it b<sub>2</sub>, and insert it into the binary tree from step (4) (insert by comparing to previously matched items from set A).
8. Repeat for a<sub>3</sub>, a<sub>4</sub>, and so on, continuing to break down set B into smaller and smaller sets and using the binary search tree to find the "correct" partitioned set to search for a<sub>k</sub> in.

Eventually you will get a time complexity like O(n) + 2* O(n / 2) + 2* O(n / 4) + 2* O(n / 8) etc.. Breaking down the problem like this using a binary search tree on every correct pairing, I believe the time complexity will be O(n log n). In the worst case it will obviously be O(n^2) just like quicksort.

Eventually you will end up with a sorted binary tree in which each node contains a pair of matching cards.